# Why did you block my Stack Overflow account for asking a question here?

Tags: support, post-ban

I wrote a post criticizing this system in a constructive manner here on Meta. Now my Stack Overflow account is blocked. The rules say if my question is about Stack Overflow it is welcome here, so my question was in the right place.

I don't think it's fair that people who dare to criticize the system in a constructive manner, get their accounts blocked as retribution. Free speech means you should tolerate constructive criticism.

It's not like the issue I mentioned is new, there's numerous complaints about the same thing I wrote about.

I'd like to request that you be so kind as to reinstate my Stack Overflow account. Thank you

Comment: Somehow *"dare to criticize the system in a constructive manner"* and *"I'm not going to conform to some ridiculous rules just to collect points"* as well as *"the tyranny of the masses you have going on here"* don't seem to match. But as said, that will have had no influence on your SO ban.

Comment: Such sweet, delicious Schadenfreude!

Comment: @Jack Maney, that's funny, but do you really think I care about this site? I'll be the one who benefits because you guys will still be answering my question under new user names. You technically won't be able to ban me, I'll just use a proxy if I have to. I will be the one not spending any time contributing, which otherwise I would have done. So this is a win situation for me, not you guys. Think about that.

Comment: I've just lost hope in humanity just a touch more.

Comment: "Free speech means you should tolerate constructive criticism." If you refer to the first amendment... ***that does not apply to private companies***.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 Oh man, you've got us there. Dammit guys, we've just been outsmarted. We seriously need to rethink this system. Like, seriously guys.....guys?

Comment: @M. Night Demonbobby True, but it should apply to any respectable professional forum.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - You haven't been the first user to attempt to circumvent the ban, and you probably won't be the last. At least you're one of the few users who are stupid enough to admit your intentions, and thus practically guaranteeing that you'll be caught. And **again**: Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Comment: @Jack Maney seriously? Are you going to ban an entire country because of me ? Otherwise you have no chance.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - I have no ability to ban anyone from Stack Overflow.

Comment: @JackManey Something tells me that's a good thing. ;)

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby: Please do not assume a US audience.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That's why I said "if you refer to".

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby "the first amendment [of the USA's constitution]" ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Touché. But I fail to find any other "first amendment"...thanks, now I'm interested in this and have to search the web...

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby The thing is, contributors are not employees of the company. They are customers (users). Can Amazon stop people who criticize them constructively from using its service? In fact, I believe a site is not worth contributing to if it bans constructive criticism. Who is gonna waste time on a forum which forbids efforts to tell the truth?

Comment: @ZiqiFan \*looks.at.wrist\* Oh wow, I think that's a record. My opinion hasn't changed since then, companies can dictate what happens on their services, simple as that, *it's their service*. Don't like it, leave it. Look, if you wanna be an arm-chair freedom warrior defending the democracy on the interwebs, be it, be my guest, just let me out of it. There's a reason I stopped contributing in such discussions.

Answer (score 21):

For the record, no one specifically blocked your account; you were placed in an automatic question ban on the main site due to the community's voting on the quality of your questions. There is no link whatsoever to your posts on Meta.

You may have brought this on yourself with your last question, by calling attention to yourself and your questions. As a result, some people may have viewed the question(s) you linked, and voted as they felt appropriate. I'm not personally always comfortable with such piling on, but it is a real 'danger' you expose yourself to when calling attention to yourself by disagreeing with the opinion of the community on the quality of your questions.

But ultimately, the quality of your questions seem to be what has caused this; you seem to perhaps have just sped up the process by calling attention to yourself. I recommend taking this opportunity to try to improve your questions; thereby possibly getting answers, and being able to post new questions.

To reiterate: note that there is no link whatsoever between your posts/votes on Meta and a question ban on the main site. You can be banned on one and not on the other.

---

As for 'Free Speech', please note that, again, no one has blocked you due to your opinion. Your expression simply called attention to your posts. But also, Stack Overflow is not a 'Free Speech' forum, per se. It's run by a private company, who have every right to limit what is said or not here. In the case of Stack Exchange, the community mostly judges that (with certain limits of decency, and the like). But it's really not relevant to use the term 'Free Speech' here, at all. Even if your opinions *were* being suppressed.

Note, for example; you were able to post *this* question...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Well it is a public, professional forum, so free speech as it relates to the IT profession should be respected, including criticism of the forum's system. These are just basic democratic values, whether run by a corporation or whatever. As for my account, I'll just create a new one to ask questions I have. If I get banned I'll just create new ones. I'm really not going to bother to do much research before asking, since I won't be contributing to this community, so I won't care about getting a reputation. Way to go guys. You can delete my account, Thanks.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 As I noted, you have *not* been blocked from expressing your opinion. And as for your plans; good luck. You haven't been getting good answers so far - what you plan to do won't help you, I guarantee. You'll just be wasting your time.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 feel free to follow the steps [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion). Don't create more accounts, it will just lead to IP ban.

Comment: @Andrew Barber I have been getting great answers, I wanted to be a part of the community but I really don't like the tyranny of the masses you have going on here. This just makes newbies like myself not invest time in contributing to the system.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 If you absolutely are not willing to take the time and effort to ask good questions, well...

Comment: @JavaMonkey22: "*free speech as it relates to the IT profession should be respected*" When means that your free speech goes *exactly* as far as the owners of that "public, professional forum" *allow* it to go. "Free speech" is about what the *government* can do, not privately-owned companies.

Comment: @Andrew Barber To be honest with you I think most of my questions were totally valid, good questions. Perhaps a few reflected lack of research, So I really have no idea why you and others say my questions aren't good. I've seen many questions showing even much less research, than the worst of mine.

Comment: @AndrewBarber You might want to expressly state in your answer that Meta participation has no influence whatsoever on a SO question ban.

Comment: @Bart Good idea; done, I think!

Comment: `s/may have brought this/have brought this/`

Comment: Just curious ? Was I banned specifically because of reaching some point value ? Or did someone make that decision ?

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - The Stack Exchange network of sites are not a democracy, and there is no guaranteed freedom of speech here.

Comment: The details of the question ban algorithm are a secret, in order to avoid gaming the system.

Comment: @JackManey I'm not sure that he didn't reach the question ban threshhold on his own, without the attention brought here. That's why I said 'may' ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - LOL, fair enough.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 Please follow [the link you get](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) in the message informing you of the ban. No person has banned you and no person can unban you. This is an automatic system.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - If you wish to delete your account, [the instructions for doing so can be found here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account). Note that if you instead create another account in an attempt to circumvent the ban, you will almost certainly be caught and IP-banned.

Comment: Ok guys, so I just happened to ask a question here criticizing the system, and at the same time the "secret algorithm" to ban me on Stack Overflow kicked in, absolutely no relation, right ? Do you expect me to believe that ? Secret algorithms, no free speech, this really does sound like tyranny of the masses, and I really would not be proud of this on a professional forum if I were you.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 re: "at the same time"... you don't seem to have read my answer very well.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - No, there is a relation. People likely saw your rant, followed your profile to your Stack Overflow, and then started downvoting your Stack Overflow questions. These downvotes were probably enough to push you into being banned from asking questions. Also, Stack Overflow is not a forum. It is a Q&A site.

Comment: @Andrew Barber I read your answer, but I honestly don't believe that my banning on Stack Overflow was not a direct consequence of some of the admins or senior users here deciding to ban me.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - Believe what you will. Let us know when you have some evidence of your ridiculous accusations.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 If you don't believe my answer, and the other information on the topic readily available here, then there is nothing else to talk about here.

Comment: @Jack Maney Obviously I won't find out the secret algorithm so I never will have evidence. The people at Stack Exchange should take a lesson in democratic values.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - Again: the Stack Exchange network of sites are not a democracy. If you want to build your own set of Q&A sites that are run in a completely democratic fashion, then feel free to leave and do so (hint, hint).

Comment: @JavaMonkey22: how exactly needs a lesson in what? Democraty doesn't mean "I am entitled to to whatever I please anywhere I please in complete disrespect & disregard for my peers".

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 4 of your SO questions have been closed. 3 have negative scores, of which one significantly. There are additionally several zero-scored questions. That seems, from experience, a decent explanation for the ban to kick in. If that is all there is (i.e. no other deleted question, possibly negatively scored) you might be on the edge. Minor improvements (gaining reputation in the process) might see you get out of the ban. You can do your how "this is so unfair" routine for a while, or work to get the ban automatically lifted. It's up to you from this point onward.

Comment: @Bart And six, negatively-voted, deleted ones.

Comment: @AndrewBarber [Well,....](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MIZ_PDXfj9U/T6AJIuFal4I/AAAAAAAAAnU/RE6CdCdZnHc/s1600/theres-your-problem.jpg).

Comment: @Bart Thanks, but I'm not going to bother, I deleted the account. I'll never know why my questions were bad, I still think most of them are good. I'll just have a new account tomorrow.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 Note that 'a good question' does not imply 'a good question for Stack Overflow'. Questions that are interesting but not correct for Stack Overflow will be downvoted anyway. Try reading the FAQ and reasons why questions can be closed/how to improve questions. Stack Overflow is not for every possible question or discussion you could possibly have, to prevent 'scope creep'.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 If you are seriously, constructively interested in knowing why your questions are regarded to be inappropriate for SO, by all means do ask. There are always Meta users willing to explain this to you. But don't rant and rave and tell us how much everything sucks. That is not going to lead to anything good. In the end you might find that you can adjust. Or perhaps even that this is not the site for you. Both are fair enough. But at this point in time you seem to be wasting energy on something entirely pointless.

Comment: @JavaMonkey22 - It seems that you are either incapable or unwilling to learn anything, so if you create another account and somehow aren't caught, then you'll find yourself banned from asking questions yet again.

Comment: Please rest assured that our system would quickly collapse on itself if we changed our rules every time someone criticized us. This site's whole job is to get us criticism. Still, as always, we're open to lessons, including those on democratic values.

Comment: Do you think the system can lead to fatigues to many contributors, finally excluding a reasonably large amount of useful questions/answers. If you do not allow someone to ask something how would someone ask a question? Whether the answer is good or bad it comes later. Is it not an "elimination process" to drive away people in every way?

Comment: Ultimately this will distract a large and growing community of skilled professionals those who are acquiring a good skill, but will not be able to post the appropriate answer or will be distracted before that. Manage to get a system to lift ban after a certain period of time as a corrective measure. Please listen to me otherwise it would be too late to save the ship ..

Comment: @PinakiSekharGupta It *is* an 'elimination process' and it *is* meant to drive certain people away - or force them to improve. If they can't improve their questions after time and time again trying, to be honest, we don't want them here.

Comment: @Andrew's a Unitato Can you please clarify what did you mean by saying "after time and time again trying"? Stackoverflow does not allow asking more than two questions if they think the questions are not up to the mark, it their own discretion. No one knows whether the question is going to be suitable for this site, the asker always give stress to the importance and complexity of the question itself, not the suitability for the site. This means someday they are surely going to be banned even if they had asked very important question that can be helpful for future reference. Not?

Comment: What about the new users? Definitely punish a fool, but don't kill them for the lifetime. Please lift the ban after 3 months. This 3 months will be adequate to teach them a lot.

Comment: @PinakiSekharGupta Three months away from the site absolutely will *not* help anyone be taught how to ask better questions here. Time *away* won't help. Working on improving skills in asking questions will. And good questions for here are simply good questions *anywhere*.

Comment: @Andrew's a Unitato Yes, "good questions for here are simply good questions anywhere". The reverse is also true, remember. If the user asks valuable questions elsewhere, it could have been added to this site. You meant if someone does not ask one or two good question here, he will be always asking bad questions everywhere. I don't see the justification. One thing I don't understand if you block someone, especially a new user with low scoring, how can he ask question and improve? Terms and conditions are telling to contribute to the site, not? What a chicken-egg cycle, Ha Ha!!!

Comment: @Andrew's a Unitato If you block someone for three months and he asks a bad question again he will be scoring negatively and blocked again for 3 months. Ultimately he will remain blocked until he tries to improve himself. At the end he will find he could save his time by improving himself. I think it is just a better method to block someone politely and teach. At least the chicken-egg problem does not come.

Comment: @PinakiSekharGupta Clearly we are not communicating well here. I'm sorry for that. I'm done here.

Comment: @Andrew's a Unitato Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/1357/